# How to add active class only on second level of the navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an vertical navigation with two levels.

What I want is when I press the main li to add active and open class just to the main `li` and when I press on the sub-menu I want to add active just to that `li`. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">
  <li class="start active open">
    <a href="javascript:;">
      <i class="icon-home"></i>
      <span class="title">Rezervari</span>
      <span class="arrow "></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
          Vezi rezervari</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon-bulb"></i>
          Istoric rezervari</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">
      <i class="icon-home"></i>
      <span class="title">Rezervari</span>
      <span class="arrow "></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
          Vezi rezervari</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon-bulb"></i>
          Istoric rezervari</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(".sub-menu li").on("click", function() {
  $(".sub-menu li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

$(".page-sidebar-menu li").on("click", function() {
  $(".page-sidebar-menu li").removeClass("active open");
  $(this).addClass("active open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the closest li inside class `.page-sidebar-menu`

```
$(".sub-menu li").on("click", function() {
      $(".sub-menu li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
});

$(".page-sidebar-menu > li").on("click", function() {
    $(".page-sidebar-menu > li").removeClass("active open");  
    $(this).addClass("active open");
});
```

Comment: almost working, but it's adding only the active class, i need to press twice to add the open one too

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understood exactly what you asked.
But, from what i get i remade your html a bit (added a menu class to bind the click event more precisely)

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200">
    <li class="menu start active open"> <a href="javascript:;">
                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                    <span class="title">Rezervari</span>
                    <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="active"> <a href="#">
                            <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
                            Vezi rezervari</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
                            <i class="icon-bulb"></i>
                            Istoric rezervari</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu"> <a href="javascript:;">
                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                    <span class="title">Rezervari</span>
                    <span class="arrow "></span>
                    </a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li> <a href="#">
                            <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
                            Vezi rezervari</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
                            <i class="icon-bulb"></i>
                            Istoric rezervari</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And so my version of your jQuery looks like that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // added a menu class to bind the click event more precisely
    $(".menu > a").on("click", function () {
        // nothing is active but this
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        // and close the other menus
        $(".menu").removeClass("open");

        $(this).parent().addClass("active open");
    });

    $(".sub-menu li").on("click", function () {
        // nothing is active but this
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

The CSS i used to test it was just this :

```
.menu { display: block; }
.sub-menu { display: none; }
.open, .open .sub-menu { display: block; }
.active { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

For an example, go check [that jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmcg7sek/) that i made to answer you (really basic css here) and tell me if that's what you asked for.